# Unable to pass -shared argument to g++ using libtool

Tags: c++, gcc, g++, libtool

I am trying to compile a shared object using libtool.

When I run the libtool command as this:

```
g++ -g -O2 -fPIC -Wl,--rpath -Wl,/opt/labris/lib/labris-lupd -o simple_text.so SimpleTextPlugin.o SimpleTextAdaptor.o SimpleTextVersionController.o FileHash.o FDiff.o FPatch.o  -L/opt/labris/lib/labris-lupd /opt/labris/lib/labris-lupd/liblupdutils.so /opt/labris/lib/labris-lupd/liblupdipc.so -lssl -Wl,-rpath -Wl,/opt/labris/lib/labris-lupd -Wl,-rpath -Wl,/opt/labris/lib/labris-lupd
```

It invokes g++ as the following:

```
libtool: link: g++ -g -O2 -fPIC -Wl,--rpath -Wl,/opt/labris/lib/labris-lupd -o simple_text.so SimpleTextPlugin.o SimpleTextAdaptor.o SimpleTextVersionController.o FileHash.o FDiff.o FPatch.o  -L/opt/labris/lib/labris-lupd /opt/labris/lib/labris-lupd/liblupdutils.so /opt/labris/lib/labris-lupd/liblupdipc.so -lssl -Wl,-rpath -Wl,/opt/labris/lib/labris-lupd -Wl,-rpath -Wl,/opt/labris/lib/labris-lupd
```

This produces the following error:

```
/usr/lib/gcc/i386-redhat-linux/4.1.2/../../../crt1.o: In function `_start':
(.text+0x18): undefined reference to `main'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

However when I invoke g++ like this with (Notice the `-shared` option at the end):

```
g++ -g -O2 -fPIC -Wl,--rpath -Wl,/opt/labris/lib/labris-lupd -o simple_text.so SimpleTextPlugin.o SimpleTextAdaptor.o SimpleTextVersionController.o FileHash.o FDiff.o FPatch.o  -L/opt/labris/lib/labris-lupd /opt/labris/lib/labris-lupd/liblupdutils.so /opt/labris/lib/labris-lupd/liblupdipc.so -lssl -Wl,-rpath -Wl,/opt/labris/lib/labris-lupd -Wl,-rpath -Wl,/opt/labris/lib/labris-lupd -shared
```

My shared object is succesfully created. I haven't been able to pass the `-shared` argument to g++ via libtool. How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding `-Xcompiler -shared` to libtool worked.

```
/usr/bin/libtool --tag=CXX --mode=link g++ -g -O2 -fPIC -Wl,--rpath -Wl,/opt/labris/lib/labris-lupd -L/opt/labris/lib/labris-lupd -Xcompiler -shared  -o simple_text.so SimpleTextPlugin.o SimpleTextAdaptor.o SimpleTextVersionController.o FileHash.o FDiff.o FPatch.o -lssl -llupdutils -llupdipc
```

This runs g++ with `-shared` argument

```
 g++ -g -O2 -fPIC -Wl,--rpath -Wl,/opt/labris/lib/labris-lupd -shared -o simple_text.so SimpleTextPlugin.o SimpleTextAdaptor.o SimpleTextVersionController.o FileHash.o FDiff.o FPatch.o  -L/opt/labris/lib/labris-lupd /opt/labris/lib/labris-lupd/liblupdutils.so /opt/labris/lib/labris-lupd/liblupdipc.so -lssl -Wl,-rpath -Wl,/opt/labris/lib/labris-lupd -Wl,-rpath -Wl,/opt/labris/lib/labris-lupd
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `-Xcompiler <parameter>` to pass parameters to compiler directly. As you've already found out, `-Xcompiler -shared` will work on your case.

Reference doc:
https://www.gnu.org/software/libtool/manual/html_node/Compile-mode.html